# How to include text qualifier as none when taking columns using csvcut (python)?

Tags: python, csv

Hy I have a csv file with the sample records below which is pipe delimited.

> 1. A|B|C|D
> 2. E|F|G|H
> 3. I|"J"||"K"|L
> 4. M|N|O|P

for the above example when I am cutting columns using csvcut and giving delimiter as '|' I am able to fetch `1st,3rd,4th row` but the `3rd row` is not coming as it is having certain field values within doublequotes.How to fetch the 3rd row also using csvcut

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
import csv
with open('a.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
   areader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
   for row in areader:
       print ' '.join(row)
```

Then you have:

```
1. A|B|C|D
2. E|F|G|H
3. I|"J"||"K"|L
4. M|N|O|P
```

Don't forget 'b' flag.